# Cucumber shared ParameterType

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

Is there a way to share custom parameter types across multiple step definitions? I have a few I'd like to not duplicate them several times over. I tried extending a `CommonStepDefintions`, but apparently step definition classes can't be extended. Any help is appreciated.

Example:

```java
public class PersonStepDefinitons {
    @Given("the person has {myenum}")
    public void personHasMyEnum(MyEnum myEnum){
        ...
    }
}
```

```java
public class AnimelStepDefinitons {
    @Given("the animel has {myenum}")
    public void animalHasMyEnum(MyEnum myEnum){
        ...
    }
}
```

How to not duplicate this?

```java
public MyEnum(String raw) {
    return MyEnum.valueOf(raw);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to duplicate it. When executing a scenario Cucumber uses all step definitions, hooks and parameters that it finds.

Cucumber searches for these on the glue path. So suppose your glue path is `com.example` then Cucumber will use everything it finds in `com.example.PersonStepDefinitons`, `com.example.AnimelStepDefinitons` and `com.example.ParameterTypes`.

If you are used to JUnit where only one class is created at once this can be a little confusing.

If things don't work, make sure everything is in the same package and double check what your IDE actually put in the run configuration.

Comment: What if my classes were structured like: `com.example.ParameterTypes`, `com.example.person.PersonStepDefinitons`, and `com.example.animal.AnimalStepDefinitons`. Would I then need a copy of the `ParameterTypes` class in both the `com.example.person` and `com.example.animal` packages? Or is there some way around this duplication as well?

Comment: Change your package structure, or change the glue path.

Comment: I tried `cucumber.glue=com.example` in `src/test/resources/cucumber.properties`, but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you want to use a custom parameter type in many different projects. Otherwise follow the steps that @M.P. Korstanje gave in his answer.

I used to solve that problem with some trick.

The example is in written Kotlin but it will not be diffucult to translate it to Java.

I have an interface in which there are lots of custom parameter types. I put this interface in a cucumber helper library source code.

```kotlin
// com.example.cucumber.helper.library

interface CucumberCustomParameterTypes {
  
  @ParameterType("yes|no|ok|ko")
  fun flag(text: String) : Boolean { // ...  }
  
}
```

In a cucumber test project, create a class in your glue path and it should `implement` your `CucumberCustomParameterTypes`. Do not forget to import your cucumber helper library to your project.

```kotlin
// com.example.yourproject

class CucumberTypes : CucumberCustomParameterTypes {
    // ...
    // additional parameter types can be defined here
}
```

Hope, it helps